# Does repeatedly sshing into more servers slow communication down?

Tags: ssh

If I ssh from my home computer into a computer in the cloud, and then I ssh from that computer to another computer and then another, does each successive ssh login slow the experience down?

In other words if I have ssh'd three computers deep is my data being transferred back and forth more slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

The reason is because instead of tunneling directly from computer A to computer D you are hopping through B, and C as well. Each computer has it's own latency and service running that must perform the proper processes to decrypt the incoming traffic from one end, and re-encrypt the traffic going out the other end.

How much is will slow down depends on the speed and connection of every computer in the chain, but if it's not possible to SSH from computer A to computer D without first going through B and C, then that is the price you must pay unless you look into restructuring your network in some way.